# TypeScript error: JSX element type 'MultiSelect' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the `react-multi-select-component` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component)

Here is how I am currently implementing it:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import Constants from '../../../../../../core/constants';
import MultiSelect from 'react-multi-select-component';
import { Option } from 'react-multi-select-component/dist/lib/interfaces';
import { useStateApi } from '../../../../../../core/hooks/state';
import {
    DropdownFilterState,
    DropdownFilterStateApi,
    dropdownFilterStateApiFactory,
} from '../state/dropdownFilterStateApiFactory';
import { filterOptions } from '../../../../helpers/DataHelpers';

export interface DropdownFilterProps {
    options: Option[];
    label: string;
    setOption?: (e: Option[]) => void;
    placeholder: string;
    allItemsSelectedText: string;
}

const DropdownFilter = (props: DropdownFilterProps): ReactElement => {

    const { options, setOption, label, placeholder, allItemsSelectedText } = props;

    const { t } = useTranslation(Constants.Localization.Namespaces.RECRUIT);

    const stateApi = useStateApi<DropdownFilterState, DropdownFilterStateApi>(
        dropdownFilterStateApiFactory,
        {
            dropdownOption: []
        }
    );

    const handleOptionChange = (e: Option[]): void => {
        stateApi.setDropdownOption(e);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        stateApi.setDropdownOption(options);
    }, [options]);

    return (

        <div id={`multi-select-${label}`} className={'mr-2'}>
            <MultiSelect
                options={options}
                value={stateApi.dropdownOption}
                onChange={(e: Option[]): void => {
                    handleOptionChange(e);
                    if (setOption){
                        setOption(e);
                    }
                }}
                filterOptions={filterOptions}
                disableSearch={false}
                defaultIsOpen={false}
                labelledBy={'Select'}
                className={`multi-select-${label}`}
                selectAllLabel={t('labels.selectAll')}
                overrideStrings={{
                    'selectSomeItems': placeholder,
                    'allItemsAreSelected': allItemsSelectedText
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default DropdownFilter;
```

Unfortunately I am met with this error whenever I `docker build .` the application or have it go through the Jenkins pipeline. Apart from that, it runs fine live via `npm start`.

```
#19 126.6     TSError: TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
#19 126.6     src/modules/project/agent/components/agents/filters/DropdownFilter.tsx:46:14 - error TS2604: JSX element type 'MultiSelect' does not have any construct or call signatures.
#19 126.6
#19 126.6     46             <MultiSelect
#19 126.6                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the docs it seems like you are not importing the right thing. You need to change from:

```js
import MultiSelect from 'react-multi-select-component';
```

To:

```js
import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up having to npm uninstall it and then npm install it with the --force flag. It resolved the error after adding the brackets.